# Custom list edit form error

Tags: 2007, custom-list, edit-form

I have created a form to replace the standard edit form. I have added it to the 'supporting documents' tab in the edit, to be used with my custom list. When I click on the 'edit' column I get a 'Unexpected error message.

Anyone had this issue?

Or have any tips and links

Answer (score 0):

The standard, out-of-the-box, method is to replace `...\Forms\EditForm.aspx` with your new file.

Note: do not delete the original file, just rename to something like `\old_EditForm.aspx`